# Export HTML Form to .PDF or .DOC

Tags: php, html, forms, pdf, doc

I have a site with some html forms (there are some text inputs, checkboxs, etc..), I need this: when user submit this forms, they will be send by a mail in pdf or doc format with filled forms. So I can print exactly the same what user submitted. What is the best or easiest way how to do this ?
Thank you

Comment: I´m using there just html and php

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this client side, it really depends on which back-end technology you are using. If you are using .NET then [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/) is a really easy to use toolkit for filling in/manipulating pdfs and .docs

For php have a look at [pdftk (pdf toolkit)](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/)

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way is using iText http://itextpdf.com

Answer (score 0):

Provided you're using PHP for processing the form you can generate an HTML summary of the form input and then convert it to PDF using a tool such as http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/